Precompile std::variant instantiation?
I am using a C++ std::variant with around 100 structs as possible choices. This type is used throughout my application and compile times tend to point to the instantiation and generation of various std::variant methods:
e.g.
Wall Duration 18,560.314 ms
Args
detail  
"std::__variant_detail::__dtor.......

Of course there are also 100's to TU's that need this definition, so my compile times are getting quite high.
With templates I'm familiar with instantiating the template in a TU for example
template class MyClass<XXX>;

Can I do a similar thing for the variant? How do I make other TU's depend on these symbols being linked in? Can I do this in a Precompiled header perhaps?

You obviously can instantiate std::variant with all your 100 structs like you shown. You can also try employing precompiled headers for the whole project or only some files that require this huge type. But to my experience, precompiled headers really mattered only with Microsoft C++ compiler, and almost didn't have effect or were even slower with gcc. Never tried with clang.

std::variant is probably not the right tool for your job.

extern template class MyClass<XXX>; will prevent template instantiation

If you have a variant with 100 template arguments, the mangled name will be massive. You can overcome this if you derive a class from variant<...100 different types here...>, and then operate with a forward declaration of that class name where ever possible. Don't let you turn down by people venting "but the type is not meant as a base class", because sometimes problems need to be solved in a pragmatic, practical manner, not in a theoretically clean manner.

@j61 And sometimes that "practical approach" results in wrong code. The destructor of std::variant is NOT virtual, so it is not designed to be derived from. Your advice is like "hey if it seems to work it is ok", which it is not

@PepijnKramer It's indeed very helpful to know what it one is doing and to weigh the pros and cons.

What I am trying to say is : do NOT derive from classes with non-virtual destructors.  It might work but you should NEVER delete such a class through its base pointer (unique/shared ofc).  And this might work for a small project you develop for yourself (because you know this)... but in larger code bases with multiple people working on it... it is going to bite you or the team

We are using Precompiled headers to great effect in CI, but the issue is local developer experience; this variant has become central to much of the code base, and so you can easily cause a recompile of like 300 TU's just poking around.

@j6t -- a non UB way to accomplish what you suggest was to make a struct Holder { std::variant<...> action; }. This has reduced the mangled name of my functions, but the std::variant::dtor etc still get instantiated where they are used.
